# python: how to find name of currently evaluating argument during function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, introspection, function-call

given the code example below: how can I get the name of argument corresponding to particular evaluation of function get_arg_val.

```
def do_sum(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c


def get_arg_val():
    print("call f") # what argument this call corresponds to: a, b or c ???
    return 1

x = do_sum(get_arg_val(), get_arg_val(), get_arg_val())
print(x)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to know what should be printed when just calling `get_arg_val()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is for tracing of program execution, could be also used in interactive debugging

Comment: @MechanicPig you could print None - i.e. the call doen't correspond to any arg evaluation

Comment: You can't. `get_arg_val` is called before `do_sum`. And you can't trace into the future.

Comment: @KlausD. can you think of any way to tell the byte code instruction of the outer frame in the call stack? you could maybe inspect the bytecode and figure something out. but it would probably be pretty brittle

Comment: I know that's very handwavy....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga As already explained `get_arg_val` is called **before** `do_sum`. There is nothing in the call stack that can be helpful to `get_arg_val`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, I understand that, but if you were able to look at the bytecode in the caller, you would see that `get_sum` is going to be called, and if you knew which bytecode instruction was being executed, you might be able to figure out which argument it's going to be applied to. I think you could make some guesses. But I'm not sure if sufficient information is kept at runtime to do it

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut well, the caller here is the module level code, (no reason to believe it is being run in a REPL). But I don't think it is relevant if it is the outermost level of the call stack. I wasn't suggesting modifying the bytecode, although that's an interesting idea, rather, I was thinking one could inspect it and trying to infer which argument the function would be passed to. I agree, it would be a lot of work and I am not sure if it will always be possible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Introspection can locate the location of function calls in Python 3.11. However, if unpacking is used in function calls (such as `func(*iterable1, get_arg_val(), *iterable2)`), since the length of iterable objects cannot be predicted only according to the code itself, we cannot know which parameter the return value will be passed to.